# Scrape several instances of a webpage the fastest way possible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So, after a lot of attempts, search and research I give up.

I have a webpage where all employees name, phone, mail and userid can be query. The way you do that is that the request to the server needs to have at least 4 digits, with all 26 ascll character + 0-9 numbers. I was able to do it with Selenium in Python...but it whould take 20 days to go through - see code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

alphanum = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1',
        '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://brnet.intra.corpintra.net/Quem/pessoas2/Default.asp')

list_base = dict()
i = 0
data_str = []
found = False

for first_chr in alphanum:
    for second_chr in alphanum:
        for third_chr in alphanum:

        text = first_chr + second_chr + third_chr

        element_name = driver.find_element_by_name('nome').clear()
        element_name = driver.find_element_by_name('nome')
        element_name.send_keys(text)
        element_search = driver.find_element_by_name('B1')
        element_search.click()

        if driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dados'):

            for table_data in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('dados'):
                cells_table = table_data.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
                for cell_data in cells_table:
                    data_str.append(cell_data.text.strip())

                if list_base:
                    for key, value in list_base.items():
                        for data in data_str:
                            if data in value:
                                found = False
                            else:
                                found = True
                else:
                    found = False
                if found is False:
                    list_base[i] = data_str
                    i = i+1

                data_str = []
                found = False

        driver.back()

w = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
for key, value in list_base.items():
    w.writerow([key, value])

driver.quit()
```

Is there a way to reduce the time?

Comment: If the page doesn't have javascript, use requests

Comment: Another option is to run jobs in parallel

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 importing the selenium request extension u mean?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko importing multiprocessing lib and using pool?

Comment: open multiple windows and do it in all of them

Comment: If this is internal, why not ask some internal group for the data or access to the db, etc.?

Comment: @JeffC ...ohhhh man...you don't know what the colleagues from ti and hr (in my case) can't do for you...they can always uncover new ways not to help

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 the thing is that the desktops that we have are really limited...like...i3 double cores with 4gb

Comment: @dormanino If you can open 4 browsers on the box (which I'm sure you can), you should be able to run 4 instances of the script. The problem is going to be breaking the search criteria down into 4 equal(ish) parts.